# How to Calculate Theoretical Probability of 4 Baby/Stork Problem

Tags: probability

So that I might not misquote in any way, here is a direct copy-pasted reference of the problem to which I am referring:

> Alternate Activity: Random Babies
>
> The ―Whose Book is This?‖ Activity
>   can be explored using the Random Babies applet at
>   [www.rossmanchance.com/applets](http://www.rossmanchance.com/applets/randomBabies/RandomBabies.html). This applet simulates a stork randomly
>   delivering four babies to four different houses and counting the
>   number of correct deliveries. Both of these problems involve
>   ―derangements,‖ and so if you want to do an Internet search and learn
>   more, search for ―derangements.‖
>
> 1. Press Randomize to have the stork deliver the babies. If there is a correct match, the sun will shine on the house, otherwise there will
>      be a storm cloud. The number of matches will be recorded in the
>      histogram.
> 2. After animating several deliveries, change the Number of trials to 10 and press Randomize. Click inside the bar above 0 to see a plot
>      that records the proportion of 0’s after each trial.
> 3. Keep pressing Randomize to add more trials to the plot. What seems to be happening to the proportion of 0’s?
> 4. The theoretical probability of 0 matches is 0.375. Based on this simulation, how would you interpret this value? (If we were to assign
>      4 babies to four houses at random over and over again, about 37.5% of
>      the time none of the babies would end up at the correct house.)

The theoretical probability of 0 matches is 0.375. The theoretical probability of 1 match is 1/3, 2 matches is 1/4 = 0.25, 3 matches is theoretically impossible (0), and the theoretical probability of all 4 correctly matching is 0.0417.

My question is: how do you calculate this? I would like to know the exact method so as to calculate these theoretical probabilities by hand, so that I could do so in altered scenarios, such as what if there were 5 storks/babies?

Thank you very much for your time. Any help is much appreciated.

I've already spent quite a bit of time researching derangements as the text suggests, but while I've found a plethora of very fun and interesting maths, I've yet to discover how to calculate these theoretical probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The number of derangements of $n$ objects, $D_n$ can be computed as $[\frac{n!}{e}]$, i,e. nearest integer to $\frac{n!}{e}$

Thus $D_4 = [\frac{4!}{e}] = 9$

For partial derangements, e.g. $k$ out of $n$ matching and $n-k$ deranged,

the formula will be $\binom{n}{k}D_{n-k}$

and probabilities can be computed by dividing by $n!$

For $n = 4$,
$P(0\;\; matches) = [\frac{4!}{e}]\div{4!} = 9\div4!=0.375$
$P(1\;\; match) = \binom41 [\frac{3!}{e}]\div 4! = 4\cdot2\div4! = 1/3$

and so on.

Btw, just in case, the formula for $\binom{n}{k}$ is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

Answer (score 0):

The probability ***P*** that none of the objects appear in their correct position:

$$
P = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}
$$

So for *n = 4* objects,

$$
P = \sum_{k=0}^{4} \dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} =
\dfrac{(-1)^{0}}{0!} +
\dfrac{(-1)^{1}}{1!} +
\dfrac{(-1)^{2}}{2!} +
\dfrac{(-1)^{3}}{3!} +
\dfrac{(-1)^{4}}{4!} =
1 - 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{6} + \dfrac{1}{24} = 
0.375
$$

I still don't know how to calculate the probability for non-zero matches.

(First time using LaTeX, pretty fun)

Comment: I'm aware that the calculations of the other non-zero match theoretical probabilities involve partial derangements.

I believe I should stop doing recreational mathematics for tonight and get on with work though; it's 1am.

Answer (score 0):

For each natural $r\ge 2$, let $S_r$ the set of permutations of $r$ distinct objects without fixed points. It is a classical result OF ALGEBRA that the number of elements of $S_r$ is $|S_r|=\sum_{j=2}^r(-1)^j(r-j)!\binom{r}{j}$.

Now, fix $n$ and $0\le k\le n$. If $X$ is the number of matches from $n$ babies, then you are asking for the distribution of $X$. That is $P(X=k)$.

Now, $P(X=k)$ is the quotient of the number of samples with exactly $k$ matches and $n-k$ errors over the number of all the possible samples. The last is simply $n!$. But for the first one, select first the matches: $\binom{n}{k}$, and then select the errors: For the first paragraph, we are searching for the total of permutations of $n-k$ distinct objects without fixed points: $|S_{n-k}|$ always that $n-k\ge 2$.

Then 
$\begin{eqnarray}P(X=k)&=&\frac{\binom{n}{k}|S_{n-k}|}{n!}\\&=&\frac{\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=2}^{n-k}(-1)^j(n-k-j)!\binom{n-k}{j}}{n!}\\&=&\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=2}^{n-k}(-1)^j\frac{(n-k)!}{j!n!}\\&=&\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-k)!}{n!}\sum_{j=2}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\\&=&\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=2}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\end{eqnarray}$

for $n-k\ge 2$. For $n-k=1$ (that is exactly n-1 matches), the probability is always 0 (if you have $n-1$ matches, automatically the restant baby is in his site). And for $n-k=0$ (that is $k=n$), the only permutation that matches all babies is the identity permutation. Then $P(X=n)=\frac{1}{n!}$

In particular, for $n=4$ we have:

1)$P(X=0)=\frac{1}{0!}\sum_{j=2}^{4-0}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}=\frac{3}{8}=0.375$

2)$P(X=1)=\frac{1}{1!}\sum_{j=2}^{4-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}=\frac{1}{3}=0.333$

3)$P(X=2)=\frac{1}{2!}\sum_{j=2}^{4-2}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}=\frac{1}{4}=0.25$

4)Since $n-k=4-3=1$, then $P(X=3)=0$.

5)Since $n-k=4-4=0$, then $P(X=4)=\frac{1}{4!}=\frac{1}{24}$.